# How can I insert a satellite image with multiple bands into PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, spatial-database, satellite

I am trying to insert a satellite image (e.g. a Sentinel Image) into PostGIS. What is the best structure to save the different bands?

I know that you can use somehow use ['ST_AddBand'](https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_AddBand.html) or ['ST_Band'](https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_Band.html), but I didn't figure out yet how to properly use them.

Answer (score 0):

This [tutorial](http://themagiscian.com/2016/08/24/change-detection-sentinel-2-postgis/) provides a very clear overview of how you can import raster data, in this case Sentinel-2  data, into PostGIS using the [`raster2pgsql`](https://postgis.net/docs/using_raster_dataman.html) tool.

Comment: Thank you @dmci for the link! But don't you normally save one satellite image with all the bands into one table, to make sure that everything that belongs together stays together? It seems kind of complicate as they make it in the tutorial, isn't it?